# how to mount /system as read/write in android?

Tags: android, system, root, mount

cannot mount /system in android with following command, anyone has a solution for this?

```
root@hwG7-UL20:/ # mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
mount: Invalid argument

255|root@hwG7-UL20:/ # mount -o remount rw /system
mount: Invalid argument

root@hwG7-UL20:/ # mount|grep system
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

the full output for mount is:

```
255|root@hwG7-UL20:/ # mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=970220k,nr_inodes=155384,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=970220k,nr_inodes=155384,mode=750,gid=1000 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,relatime,memory 0 0
none /dev/frz cgroup rw,relatime,freezer 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=970220k,nr_inodes=155384,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=970220k,nr_inodes=155384,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
adb /dev/usb-ffs/adb functionfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/log /log vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1007,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/persist /persist ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modem /firmware vfat ro,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0337,dmask=0227,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/data/media /mnt/shell/emulated sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cust /cust ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you should ask this on AndroidEnthusiasts. Make sure it's not a duplicate question, there are a lot of questions on how to mount /system.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll try to find help there:)

Comment: Totally the same problem, OTA update fixed it

Comment: Dup of https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149434/how-to-mount-system-as-read-write-in-android